# Page refreshing after the parameter selection in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I have couple of parameters in my SSRS report. some are multivalued and some are regular with drop down list. each time while selecting a different parameter value the page is getting refreshed. Is there any way to avoid this  page refreshment on each parameter selection.

Thanks in advance. 
Maria

Comment: are they linked parameters? ie - the value of one drives the drop down list for the second?

Answer (score 5):

I just encountered to this problem today, and the following post definitely helped me.

http://blog.summitcloud.com/2009/12/fix-refresh-of-parameters-in-ssrs/

quoting from the post:

> According to Microsoft, if a default value or valid values list is
>   “too complex” (could be as simple as `=Year()` expression) for the RS
>   engine to comprehend at runtime it will determine that it is dependent
>   and therefore a candidate for refreshing.

The post in the link shows a simple workaround example:

> If you can, take those VB expressions and turn them into datasets that
>   return values based on an SQL statement.   So `=Year()`  in the
>   expression would become something like `Select Year(getdate()) as CurYear`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Not easily unless you willing to roll your own report viewer control. This is done because SSRS has parameters which can be used to determine the value of other parameters. For example imagine your looking at website users and your first option is OS, perhaps it has Vista, XP, and Mac.

When you select Vista the page refreshesh to get a list of all the various versions of Vista.

If you are using thing like this, then you won't be able to prevent the refresh.

Answer (score 2):

In this example, I have tried for the `DateTime` parameter postback

Hope it works for you as well

For the `DateTime` field in the Parameters make first a parameter as dummy Date value & then assign this `DateTime` value to the actual `DateTime` parameters of the report.

Suppose we have a Stored Procedure where we have to supply *From Date* and *To Date*

1. In the Report parameters, add a dummy `DateTime` parameter `Datetime_Dummy` as the `Name` and `DateTime` as the `DataType`
2. Make it hidden
3. In the **Default Values** section, select **Specify values**
4. Set the expression to `=Today()`
5. Make sure that this is the first `DateTime` parameter in the datetimes parameter
6. Set the `FromDate` parameter's `DataType` to `DateTime`
7. In the **Default Values** section, select **Specify values**
8. Set the expression to `=Parameters!Datetime_Dummy.Value`

This prevents the page from posting back when a new `From` date is selected.

Comment: Thanks, this was the only one that worker for me. Even if it is a hack.

Answer (score 1):

Following is an approach that worked for me based on a post I read elsewhere.

In my scenario I had a boolean parameter for which I had provided Yes and No captions and corresponding true and false values directly (not via a query). I also had 2 date time parameters. None of these were tied with each other.

Every time, I entered values for any of the dayes and tabbed over, SSRS would refresh itself. It seems SSRS tries to resolve the expressions which in my case were the values for the Yes and NO options.

**The solution** was to use a dataset to return the Yes and No values which resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather long to resolve, However I was able to figure it out.
The page keeps refreshing because you have dependencies between paremeters (The Last parameter you create, depends on all the ones that you created before it)

In order to resolve this you will need to follow these steps to remove the dependencies:

1)Right Click on the Datasets folder on the Report Data pane -> Show Hidden Datasets (SSRS 2008 automatically creats a dataset for each parameter that you add)

2)Double click on each Hidden Dataset that appeared (namely the parameter datasets) -> Query -> Query Designer , on the top right there is like a blue triangle on top of a ruler (Design Mode), and at the end of the query where it says From [Database Name], you will need to erase everything before that until (not including) ON ROWS (the first ON ROWS from the bottom) ALSO DELETE ALL THE CLOSING BRACKETS')' AT THE END OF THE QUERY

3)click ok to apply changes then click on parameters and delete everything in that list, and press ok to apply.

4)Expand the Parameters folder in Report Data, Double click on each parameter ->Advanced-> Never Refresh

This should take care of the refreshing :)
Thank you,
Chris

Comment: I Right clicked Report Data Pan, but there is no menu item to show hidden datasets. I get only "Add Dataset". Any idea pls?

Answer (score 0):

For me this was resolved by disabling X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff custom header in the web.config.

```html
<customHeaders>
   <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
   <!-- 
   <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
 THIS BREAKS SSRS REPORTS, causes clickable controls to immediately reload page
 -->
    <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
</customHeaders>
```

Answer (score -2):

I have done this many times ago this was just removal of parameters dependency with various permutation and combinations as per need in projects.

Just do following things.

1. Remove all dependency of parameters from the drop down population of data.
2. Pass default values under each report parameters.

I hope it will helpful.

Thank You.